# no overload for the method xyz() with out parameters take 4 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service like

```
 public void AbcXyz(string unm, string pass, out string status, out string Utype)
 {

 }
```

and i have added the reference of this web service to my solution, created a object to this webservice and called the web method like this

```
 srv.AbcXyz(Uname, encryptPswd,out result, out Utype);
```

Here i am getting an error

```
"No Overload for method 'AbcXyz' takes '4' arguments"
```

I really dnt understand why i am getting this error. can someone please help me in this issue..

Regards,
vijayUV

Comment: Have you changed the web service method after you added the service to your solution?  If so you will need to update the service in your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated your web references?

Are you sure you're using the most up-to-date version?

What does intellisense show when you start typing "srv.AbcXyz"?

---

**EDIT:**

There must be something you're not updating.

1. Compile your WS project.
2. In your WS test calling the culprit method
3. In the consumer project update your WebReferences.
4. In the references file browse for the method. Check whether it has the signature you expect.

This *ought to* work! I'll wait for your feedback

Comment: I have deleted the web reference and again added the web reference after rebuilding the web service, but still im facing the same problem and I am sure that I am using the updated version

Comment: @vijayUV: And what about the intellisense. Does it show the method with the expected parameters?

Comment: It is showing only 3 parameters like srv.AbcXyz(string unm, string pass, out string Utype)

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently change this method?  I'm going a little out of my area of expertise here, but I know that with WCF you have to run something that generates a file that the consuming code uses to know what the service looks like.  If creating a web services has a similar process, then maybe you need to go through that process again.

In other words, maybe the code calling the service is looking to an old file that's not telling it there's a method with 4 parameters yet.

Comment: You're right. In Webservices you need to update the consumer's references whenever there are changes in the signature of the WebMethods.